# Prevent loading PrimeFaces theme.css from a single page only

Tags: jsf, primefaces, themes, jsf-2.2

How can I prevent loading PrimeFaces theme.css from a single page only?

Comment: I don't know of any solution to do it for just one page.

Answer (score 0):

Add dependencies to your pom.xml:

```
<!-- PrimeFaces Framework -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- PrimeFaces All Themes -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Add this configuration to web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>#{themeBean.theme}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You need to create an **eager** bean with **@ApplicationScoped** to load and manage your configuration:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "themeBean", eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class ThemeBean {

    private String theme = "none";

    public void setTheme(String theme) {
        this.theme = theme;
    }

    public String getTheme() {
        return theme;
    }
}
```

Using the start configuration "none" in theme name you will prevent theme.css file be created, but if you need change this just set the new value like "bootstrap" to load another theme.

> Instead of remove the theme.css, you really should consider create a custom theme.